# Implementing wordpress query function from one to another

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins

Old source code

```html
<?php 
/*
Template Name: Daily Suggestions
*/
?>

<link rel="stylesheet" id="su-box-shortcodes-css"  href="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri()?>/css/box-shortcodes.css?ver=4.9.0" type="text/css" media="all" />



<?php get_header(); ?>
 <div class="content dailysuggestion">
  <?php tie_breadcrumbs() ?>
  <div class="page-head">
   <h1 class="page-title">
    Daily Suggestions
                <?php //the_title(); ?>
   </h1>
  </div>





            


<?php 
    
    
    $post_s = array();
    
    //add_filter( 'posts_where', 'filter_where_next_week' );
    $query = new WP_Query('posts_per_page=50&paged=1&cat=33');    //$query_string. '&post_status=scheduled' 
    if( $query->have_posts() ) :
    while( $query->have_posts() ) :
      $query->the_post();
      
      //echo '<pre>';print_r($post);echo '</pre>';
      
      $post_s[$post->ID]['title'] = $post->post_title;
      //the_title();
      
      
      $post_s[$post->ID]['date'] = $post->post_date;
      //the_date();

    endwhile;
    else : echo 'nothing scheduled in next week';
    endif; wp_reset_postdata();
    //remove_filter( 'posts_where', 'filter_where_next_week' );
    
?>


<section class="cat-box wide-box">
    <div class="su-tabs su-tabs-style-default" data-active="1">
        <div class="su-tabs-nav">

<?php 

$start   = new DateTime();
$end     = new DateTime();

//$start   = $start->modify( '-7 days' ); 
$end     = $end->modify( '+7 days' ); // Date Period doesn't include the end date

$interval = new DateInterval('P1D');
$daterange = new DatePeriod($start, $interval ,$end);

foreach($daterange as $date){
    
    echo '<span class="">';
    echo $date->format("D").'<br />';
  
    echo '</span>';

}


?>

        </div>
        
        <div class="su-tabs-panes">
            <div class="cat-box-content">
    <ul>


<?php 


    foreach($daterange as $date){
        
        echo '<div class="su-tabs-pane su-clearfix" style="display: none;">';
        
  $has_post = false;
        foreach($post_s as $post_k => $post_i) {   
            if( date('Y-m-d', strtotime($post_i['date'])) == $date->format('Y-m-d')) {
                
                $post = get_post( $post_k );    
                //echo '<pre>';print_r($post);echo '</pre>';
                //wp_get_single_post($post_k);
?>
     <li <?php tie_post_class( 'first-news' ); ?>><?php //echo '--->'.$Cat_ID; ?>
      <div class="inner-content">
      <?php if ( function_exists("has_post_thumbnail") && has_post_thumbnail() ) : ?>   
       <div class="post-thumbnail">
        <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php printf( esc_attr__( 'Permalink to %s', 'tie' ), the_title_attribute( 'echo=0' ) ); ?>" rel="bookmark">
         <?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?>
         <span class="overlay-icon"></span>
        </a>
       </div><!-- post-thumbnail /-->
      <?php endif; ?>
     
      <h2 class="post-box-title"><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php printf( esc_attr__( 'Permalink to %s', 'tie' ), the_title_attribute( 'echo=0' ) ); ?>" rel="bookmark"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>
      
       <?php get_template_part( 'includes/boxes-meta' ); ?>     
       <div class="entry">
        <?php echo substr($post->post_content, 0, 200); //the_content(); ?>
        <a class="more-link" href="<?php the_permalink() ?>"><?php _e( 'Read More &raquo;', 'tie' ) ?></a>
       </div>
      </div>
     </li><!-- .first-news -->


<?php
                //echo '<br />'.$post_k;
                //echo '<br />'.$post_i['title'];
    $has_post = true;
            }
            
        }
  
  if($has_post == false)echo '<h2>No Daily Suggestions for today</h2>';
        
        echo '</div>';



    }

?>
    </ul>
    <div class="clear"></div>
   </div>



        </div>
    </div>

</section>











</div>

<?php get_sidebar(); ?>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

New Source Code

```html
<?php
/*
Plugin Name: Event Organiser Posterboar
Version: 1.1.0
define( 'EVENT_ORGANISER_POSTERBOARD_VER', '1.1.0' );
define( 'EVENT_ORGANISER_POSTERBOARD_DIR',plugin_dir_path(__FILE__ ) );
function _eventorganiser_posterboard_set_constants(){
 /*
  * Defines the plug-in directory url
 * <code>url://mysite.com/wp-content/plugins/event-organiser-posterboard</code>
 */
 define( 'EVENT_ORGANISER_POSTERBOARD_URL',plugin_dir_url(__FILE__ ));


}
add_action( 'after_setup_theme', '_eventorganiser_posterboard_set_constants' );


function eventorganiser_posterboard_register_stack( $stacks ){
 $stacks[] = EVENT_ORGANISER_POSTERBOARD_DIR . 'templates';
 return $stacks;
}
add_filter( 'eventorganiser_template_stack', 'eventorganiser_posterboard_register_stack' );

function eventorganiser_posterboard_register_styles(){
 $ver = EVENT_ORGANISER_POSTERBOARD_VER;
 wp_register_style( 'eo_posterboard', EVENT_ORGANISER_POSTERBOARD_URL.'css/event-board.css', array(), $ver );
}
add_action( 'init', 'eventorganiser_posterboard_register_styles' );

function eventorganiser_posterboard_register_scripts(){
 $ext = (defined( 'SCRIPT_DEBUG' ) && SCRIPT_DEBUG) ? '' : '.min';
 $ver = EVENT_ORGANISER_POSTERBOARD_VER;
 wp_register_script( 'eo_posterboard', EVENT_ORGANISER_POSTERBOARD_URL."js/event-board{$ext}.js", array( 'jquery', 'jquery-masonry' ), $ver ); 
}
add_action( 'init', 'eventorganiser_posterboard_register_scripts' );


function eventorganiser_posterboard_shortcode_handler( $atts = array() ){
 
 $defaults = array( 'filters' => "" );
 $query    = array_diff_key( (array) $atts, $defaults );
 $atts     = shortcode_atts( $defaults, $atts );
 
 //Get template
 ob_start();
 eo_locate_template( 'single-event-board-item.html', true, false );
 $template = ob_get_contents();
 ob_end_clean();
 
 //Load & 'localize' script
 if( !eventorganiser_get_option( 'disable_css' ) ){
  wp_enqueue_style( 'eo_posterboard' );
 }
 wp_enqueue_script( 'eo_posterboard' );

 wp_localize_script( 'eo_posterboard', 'eventorganiser_posterboard',
  array(
   'url'       => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ),
   'loading'   => __( 'Loading...', 'event-organiser-posterboard' ),
   'load_more' => __( 'Load more', 'event-organiser-posterboard' ),
   'template'  => $template,
   'query'     => $query
  ));
 
 
 //Handle filters 
 $filters = explode(',', $atts['filters']);
 $filers_markup = '';
 
 $venues = eo_get_venues();
 $cats = get_terms( array('event-category'), array('hide_empty'=> false ) );

 //'state'/'country'/'city' functions only available in Pro
 $is_pro_active = in_array( 'event-organiser-pro/event-organiser-pro.php', (array) get_option( 'active_plugins', array() ) );
 
 if( $filters ):
 
 foreach( $filters as $filter ){
  
  $filter = strtolower( trim( $filter ) );
  
  switch( $filter ):
 
   case 'venue':
    if( $venues ){
     foreach( $venues as $venue ){
   
      $filers_markup .= sprintf(
        '<a href="#" class="eo-eb-filter eo-eb-filter-venue eo-eb-filter-venue-%1$d" data-filter-type="venue" data-venue="%1$d" data-filter-on="false">%2$s</a>',
        $venue->term_id,
        $venue->name
       );
     }  
    }
   break;
  
   case 'category':
    if( $cats ){
     foreach( $cats as $cat ){
      $filers_markup .= sprintf(
       '<a href="#" class="eo-eb-filter eo-eb-filter-category eo-eb-filter-category-%1$d" data-filter-type="category" data-category="%1$d" data-filter-on="false">%2$s</a>',
       $cat->term_id,
       $cat->name
      );
     }
    }
    $filers_markup .= sprintf(
     '<a href="#" class="eo-eb-filter eo-eb-filter-category eo-eb-filter-category-%1$d" data-filter-type="category" data-category="%1$d" data-filter-on="false">%2$s</a>',
     0,
     __( 'Uncategorised', 'event-organiser-posterboard' )
    );
   break;
   
   case 'city':
   case 'state':
   case 'country':
    
    //If Pro isn't active, this won't work
    if( !$is_pro_active )
     break;
    
    if( 'city' == $filter ){
     $terms = eo_get_venue_cities();
    }elseif( 'state' == $filter ){
     $terms = eo_get_venue_states();
    }else{
     $terms  = eo_get_venue_countries();
    }
    
    if( $terms ){
     foreach( $terms as $term ){
      $filers_markup .= sprintf(
       '<a href="#" class="eo-eb-filter eo-eb-filter-%1$s eo-eb-filter-%1$s-%2$s" data-filter-type="%1$s" data-%1$s="%2$s" data-filter-on="false">%2$s</a>',
       $filter,
       $term
      );
     }      
    }
   break;
  endswitch;
 }
 endif;
 
 return
  '<div id="event-board">' 
   .'<div id="event-board-filters" data-filters="">'. $filers_markup . '</div>'  
   .'<div id="event-board-items"></div>'
   .'<div id="event-board-more"></div>'
  .'</div>';
}
add_shortcode( 'event_board', 'eventorganiser_posterboard_shortcode_handler' );


function eventorganiser_posterboard_ajax_response(){

 $page  = isset( $_GET['page'] ) ? (int) $_GET['page'] : 1;
 $query = empty( $_GET['query'] ) ? array() : $_GET['query'];


 foreach ( array( 'category', 'tag', 'venue' ) as $tax ){
  if( isset( $query['event_'.$tax] ) ){
   $query['event-'.$tax] = $query['event_'.$tax];
   unset( $query['event_'.$tax] );
  }
 }
 
 if( isset( $query['event-venue'] ) && $query['event-venue']== '%this%' ){
  if( eo_get_venue_slug() ){
   $query['event-venue'] = eo_get_venue_slug();
  }else{
   unset( $query['event-venue'] );
  }
 }
 
 if( isset( $query['users_events'] ) && strtolower( $query['users_events'] ) == 'true' ){
  $query['bookee_id'] = get_current_user_id();
 }

 
 $query = array_merge( 
  array(
   'event_start_after' => 'today',
   'posts_per_page'    => 10,
  ),
  $query,
  array(
   'post_type'         => 'event',
   'paged'             => $page,
   //'post_status'       => true,//get_post_stati( array('public' => true) )
   'post_status'       => array( 'publish', 'private' ), 
   'perm'              => 'readable'
  )
 );
 
 $event_query = new WP_Query( $query );
 
 $response = array();
 if( $event_query->have_posts() ){
  
  global $post;
  
  while( $event_query->have_posts() ){
   
   $event_query->the_post();
   $start_format = get_option( 'time_format' );
   
   if( eo_get_the_start( 'Y-m-d' ) == eo_get_the_end( 'Y-m-d' )  ){
    $end_format = get_option( 'time_format' );
   }else{
    $end_format = 'j M '.get_option( 'time_format' );
   }
   
   $venue_id   = eo_get_venue();
   $categories = get_the_terms( get_the_ID(), 'event-category' );
   $colour     = ( eo_get_event_color() ? eo_get_event_color() : '#1e8cbe' );
   $address    = eo_get_venue_address( $venue_id );
   
   $event = array(
    'event_id'             => get_the_ID(),
    'occurrence_id'       => $post->occurrence_id,
    'event_title'         => get_the_title( ),
    'event_color'         => $colour,
    'event_color_light'   => eo_color_luminance( $colour, 0.3 ),
    'event_start_day'     => eo_get_the_start( 'j'),
    'event_start_month'   => eo_get_the_start( 'M' ),
    'event_content'       => get_the_excerpt(),
    'event_thumbnail'     => get_the_post_thumbnail( get_the_ID(), array( '200', '200' ), array( 'class' => 'aligncenter' ) ),
    'event_permalink'     => get_permalink(),
    'event_categories'    => get_the_term_list( get_the_ID(),'event-category', '#', ', #', '' ),
    'event_venue'         => ( $venue_id ? eo_get_venue_name( $venue_id ) : false ),
    'event_venue_id'      => $venue_id,
    'event_venue_city'    => ( $venue_id ? $address['city'] : false ),
    'event_venue_state'   => ( $venue_id ? $address['state'] : false ),
    'event_venue_country' => ( $venue_id ? $address['country'] : false ),
    'event_venue_url'     => ( $venue_id ? eo_get_venue_link( $venue_id ) : false ),
    'event_is_all_day'    => eo_is_all_day(),
    'event_cat_ids'       =>  $categories ? array_values( wp_list_pluck( $categories, 'term_id' ) ) : array( 0 ), 
    'event_range'         => eo_get_the_start( $start_format ) . ' - ' . eo_get_the_end( $end_format ),
   );
   
   $event = apply_filters( 'eventorganiser_posterboard_item', $event, $event['event_id'], $event['occurrence_id'] );
   $response[] = $event;
  }
 }

 wp_reset_postdata();
 
 echo json_encode($response);
 exit;
}
add_action( 'wp_ajax_eventorganiser-posterboard', 'eventorganiser_posterboard_ajax_response' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_eventorganiser-posterboard', 'eventorganiser_posterboard_ajax_response' );
```

How do i bring forward the $event_query function from my new source code to old source code? I'm doing this because I want to keep the UI from my old source code.. Thanks in advance.. really need help

Comment: Please post a [minimal working example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of your problem.

Comment: @Daerst In instance? Example of ?

Comment: The code you posted is pretty large and not many poeple will read it. Try shortening the code to the relevant parts.

Comment: @Daerst I really have no idea which part i need and i don't need ): I will really appreciate if you can through it and help me out.